# How to rewrite full updated json instead of only the nested part

Tags: java, json

I have a json file called test.json that looks like:

```
{
  "Added": {
    "type": "K",
    "newmem": {
      "IDNew": {
        "id": "777709",
        "type": "LOP"
      },
      "birthDate": "2000-12-09"
    },
    "code": "",
    "newest": {
      "curlNew": "",
      "addedForNew": ""
    }
  }
}
```

I am able to update the id in the json and write back to the file using the following code:

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader(filePath); //where file path = D://.../test.json
String keyToUpdate = "Added.newmem.IDNew.id"
String[] keyArr = jsonKey.split("\\." );
String keyToUpdate = keyArr [keyArr.length-1]
keyArr.removeElement(keyArr, keyToUpdate)
for (String key: keyArr){ 
   jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get(key);
}

jsonObject.put("id",12345);
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
byte[] strToBytes = jsonObject.toString().getBytes();
outputStream.write(strToBytes);
```

However, instead of re-writing the entire json with the updated value, it's only writing:

```
  {
    "id": "777709",
    "type": "LOP"
  }
```

What can I do to re-write the entire json instead of only the nested part of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jsonObject before update only contains the "IDNew" node.

The best way to do this is using xPath from [Jayway](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)

```
private static final Configuration configuration = Configuration.builder()
    .jsonProvider(new JacksonJsonNodeJsonProvider())
    .mappingProvider(new JacksonMappingProvider())
    .build();



    String originalJson = "{\r\n"
            + "  \"Added\": {\r\n"
            + "    \"type\": \"K\",\r\n"
            + "    \"newmem\": {\r\n"
            + "      \"IDNew\": {\r\n"
            + "        \"id\": \"777709\",\r\n"
            + "        \"type\": \"LOP\"\r\n"
            + "      },\r\n"
            + "      \"birthDate\": \"2000-12-09\"\r\n"
            + "    },\r\n"
            + "    \"code\": \"\",\r\n"
            + "    \"newest\": {\r\n"
            + "      \"curlNew\": \"\",\r\n"
            + "      \"addedForNew\": \"\"\r\n"
            + "    }\r\n"
            + "  }\r\n"
            + "}";

JsonNode updatedJson = JsonPath.using(configuration).parse(originalJson).set("$.Added.IDNew.id", 12345).json();

System.out.println(updatedJson.toString());
}
```

Comment: This code is throwing com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Missing property in path $['Added']['IDNew']

Comment: I added .options(Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS) - I am now getting java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode cannot be cast to class java.util.List (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.List is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Comment: I got the path wrong, try “$.Added.newmem.IDNew.id